# Get Last n Months Data Group by Week - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am trying to get last 4 months data filtered by week in Laravel. This is code I currently have:

```
$analytics =
        Data::select([
            DB::raw('WEEK(p_date_time) AS week'),
            DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS count'),
        ])
            ->where('p_id', $p_id)
            ->where('p_date_time', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth(4))
            ->groupBy('week')
            ->orderBy('week')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();
```

This code gives me 52 results based on Data for 1 full year (As I am using WEEK). But I need around 17 results for the last 4 months.

I can make that happen by gathering of each day and then adding 7 days data as chunk for last 4 months, but how can I do it with query alone?

Thanks.

Comment: your code should be okay, it will return data from 4 month ago. i test your query and it's return expected result. can you provide your return array in your example ? and is your `p_date_time` is `date` or `timestamp` format in your database ?

Comment: @martiendt, currently p_date_time is in date and it successfully returns data for my other queries. This is the data I am getting:

[{"week":1,"count":1},{"week":2,"count":1},{"week":3,"count":12},{"week":8,"count":14},{"week":9,"count":274},{"week":46,"count":2},{"week":47,"count":2},{"week":48,"count":1},{"week":49,"count":3},{"week":50,"count":3},{"week":51,"count":2},{"week":52,"count":3}]

I am confused here as well. Normally WEEK returns data of last 1 year. But I have set time limit of 4 months by Carbon::now()->subMonth(4). Then how it returns data older than 17 week?

Comment: hmm, i think need more debug on this, try to remove `DB::raw('WEEK(p_date_time) AS week')` so we can see your selected date clearly

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a typo in your Carbon query. Change `subMonth(4)` to `subMonths(4)`. With 's'.

Comment: it's returns the same value whether I use subMonth(4) or subMonths(4),